# How to better denote the result of ifelse (D>C,C/D,D/C) mathematically?

Tags: notation

The absolute value allows me to denote the difference between A and B regardless of which one is bigger, like so: $|A-B|$ or abs(A-B) in e.g. R.

I'm trying to correctly denote a formula where i do the same with division of two positive numbers (say, $C$ and $D$). Again, i don't care which one is bigger, but i want the resulting ratio to be between $0$ and $1$. So the intended answer is $C/D$ if $D$ is bigger, and its reciprocal if $C$ is bigger. When i code this in R i can simply do: ifelse(D>C,C/D,D/C).

But is there a way to denote my desired result in a mathematically more acceptable way? Thanks so much!

Comment: How about $\min \{D/C, C/D\}$?

Comment: I like this question. We are indeed missing a function that returns the largest of a number and its inverse, implementable as $\exp(|\ln x|)$.

Comment: What about $|x|_\bullet$  or $|x|_\times$ or $|||x|||$ for the "absolute magnitude" ?

Comment: Thanks! Many ways to arrive at the answer using functions, none are wrong, but i was wondering about notation regardless of what a particular software might call functions like min{} or if() etc. 
@Yves Daoust: is your 2nd comment a universally accepted notation? (What does the dot mean?)

Comment: @MarloesEeftens: not at all. I have never met any notation for this.

Answer (score 3):

What about
$$
\frac{\min\{C,D\}}{\max\{C,D\}}?
$$

We can write
$$
\min\{C,D\} = \frac{C+D-|C-D|}{2}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\max\{C,D\} = \frac{C+D+|C-D|}{2},
$$
so one could combine these two and only have addition, subtraction, division, and absolute values.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just add my comment as an answer:

How about
$$
\min\left\{\frac{C}{D}, \frac{D}{C}\right\}
$$
?

The min/max functions are in R and this is perfectly mathematically acceptable since you note that $C,D > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that uses the [sign/signum function](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiM_5qyjuHVAhVPxGMKHbBoA48QFggwMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSign_function&usg=AFQjCNFYI_JLmxUKnJxY4tBWWNiEdNoMlw):

$$\left(\frac{C}{D}\right)^{\text{sgn}(D-C)}$$

If $C>D$ then this gives $\left(\frac{C}{D}\right)^{-1}$

If $C=D$ then this gives $\left(\frac{C}{D}\right)^{0}$

If $C<D$ then this gives $\left(\frac{C}{D}\right)^{1}$